# VSCode Git Notifications?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm coming from IntelliJ, where you get notifications about an action when its done, i.e. (10 files updated after git pull) or (push successful) ect. Is there a setting to do this VSCode? It just awkwardly stops the progress bar with no status update.